# Remove html from title (wordpress)

Tags: xml, title

I use a import plugin for products, the products imported from xml file (by url), one xml file has this string in titles:

```
< product_title >
< ![CDATA[
< font color=red >All cities:< /font > Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. !
]] >
< /product_title >
```

What is the function to remove this from my titles: `< font color=red > .. < /font >`
(it appear as is, with no encode)

Thanks a lot,
Stathis

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) in PHP.

```
<title><?php echo strip_tags($title); ?></title>
```

---

```
<h1 class="page-title"> <?php if (strlen($btp_title) > 160) { $btp_title = substr($btp_title, 0, 160).'...'; } echo esc_html( $btp_title ); ?> </h1>
```

would become

```
<h1 class="page-title"> <?php if (strlen($btp_title) > 160) { $btp_title = substr($btp_title, 0, 160).'...'; } echo strip_tags( esc_html( $btp_title ) ); ?> </h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

this is my title, can you please make the combination, Thanks

<h1 class="page-title">

<?php
if (strlen($btp_title) > 160) {
$btp_title = substr($btp_title, 0, 160).'...';
}

echo esc_html( $btp_title );
?>

</h1>

Comment: @Stathis_k9 I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: @Stathis_k9 What do you mean "not working"? Are you getting an error? Does it not output like you want? You're being very very vague.

Comment: @Stathis_k9 Try to switch around the `esc_html` and `strip_tags` function. I don't know what `esc_html` does, and wordpresses SVN trunk is down.